# Does $\lim_{|(u, v)|\to +\infty}\frac{f(x, u, v)}{|u|^p +|v|^q}=+\infty$ implies that $\lim_{|(u, v)|\to +\infty}\frac{f(x, u, v)}{|u|^p}=+\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and let $f:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Let $p, q\in\mathbb{R}, p, q>1$ and suppose that
$$\lim_{|(u, v)|\to +\infty}\frac{f(x, u, v)}{|u|^p +|v|^q}=+\infty.$$

My question is: it is possible to deduce from the above relation that also
$$\lim_{|(u, v)|\to +\infty}\frac{f(x, u, v)}{|u|^p}=+\infty?$$

If yes, how to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The fraction in the second expression is always larger than the fraction in the first.

Comment: Please tag questions with 'functional-analysis' only if there happens to appear some infinite-dimensional space. Questions on analysis of some functions do not belong there. (Even if the invisible context is in pde's etc).

Comment: @daw okay for the tag. With your first comment you mean that the answer is no?

Comment: He meant the answer is yes. I give you details below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in \Omega$ be given and fixed. For a given $M>0$, we can choose $\delta>0$ such that $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}>\delta$ implies $f(x,u,v)>M(|u|^p+|v|^q)>M|u|^p$. So the second limit is always correct assuming the first.